# Android - setListAdapter() + notifyDataSetChanged() clarification

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a `ListFragment` whose data is populated by a custom adapter ( a `SimpleAdapter` in my case). I was experiencing issues with using `notifyDataSetChanged()` from within my class that extended `ListFragment`. After a lot of looking around and several (useful) Stack Overflow posts later:

[listview not updating with notifydatasetchanged() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747553/listview-not-updating-with-notifydatasetchanged-call)

[Android ListView not refreshing after notifyDataSetChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503006/android-listview-not-refreshing-after-notifydatasetchanged)

[adapters notifyDataSetChanged does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958458/adapters-notifydatasetchanged-does-not-work)

[notifyDataSetChanged not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598621/notifydatasetchanged-not-working)

[ListView does not update when calling notifyDataSetChanged from a BaseAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375931/listview-does-not-update-when-calling-notifydatasetchanged-from-a-baseadapter)

I understand that a loose (and highly un-recommended) workaround would be to re-set your adapter using `setListAdapter()`. However I am now facing issues with this as well.

The documentation, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter), mentions that `setListAdapter()`

> Provides the cursor for the list view.

But I still have some questions.

Q1. Does initializing an adapter multiple times using setListAdapter() 'point' to the same adapter instance ?

Q2. What actually happens when a call is made to getListAdapter() and then to notifyDataSetChanged() when an adapter has been set multiple times using setListAdapter() ?

Q3. This question is based on an assumption from Q2-  when `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called when an adapter is set multiple times, which of those adapter instances (this part is the assumption), if they exist' is actually being notified for change ?

I am a beginner with Android and I believe there a quite a few nuances I do not understand.I would be extremely grateful if you could clarify these questions. Also thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Does initializing an adapter multiple times using setListAdapter() 'point' to the 
    same adapter instance ?

`Ans:` Initializing the adapter will point only to the last instance that you set using `setListAdapter`.

```
Q2. What actually happens when a call is made to getListAdapter() and then to 
notifyDataSetChanged() when an adapter has been set multiple times using 
setListAdapter() ?
```

`Ans:` It doesn't matter how many adapters that you have initialized, only the last instance will be retrieved using the `getListAdapter()`.When you use `notifyDataSetChanged()` only the last instance wich is retrieved using `getListAdapter()` will be refreshed i.e. ; the last instance will be reloaded(By calling the `getView`).

```
Q3. This question is based on an assumption from Q2- when notifyDataSetChanged() is 
called when an adapter is set multiple times, which of those adapter instances (this 
part is the assumption), if they exist' is actually being notified for change ?
```

`Ans:` The above answer contains the explanation for this.

Comment: Could you rephrase the following sentences? *and when you use notifyDataSetChanged() only the last instance will be refreshed i.e. ; the last instance will be reloaded(By calling the getView)*,

Comment: please check the above is ok